# upload of large data when using R to do t test

Tags: r, statistics

I'm right now using R to do two-sample t test.
I see lots of script examples on internet like below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

dataset.1= c(498, 460, 468, 458, 530, 482, 528, 598, 456)
dataset.2= c(596, 422, 524, 454, 538, 552, 478, 564, 556)


t.test(dataset.1, dataset.2, paired=T,conf.level=0.9)
```

OK this works well to me. But my problem is: I have a huge data input like below:

```
GENE CANCER1 CANCER2 CANCER3 NORMAL1 NORMAL2 NORMAL3
gene1 123    232   322   898  988  899
.....
.....
gene7000  233 434 434 897 676 654
```

Then how can I upload this data (path+xxx.txt) to the script?

Also more importantly, how can I specifically point out certain columns in my script?
say now I hope to compare `data1=c(233,434,434,)` and `data2=c(897,676,654)` for gene7000?

Thanks

Comment: are you looking for read.table?

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty simple. You can pass any arguments you want to your `R` script on the command lines. You can pass file names, the name of a vector or the number of a column, etc. To get the arguments from within `R` do something like this:

```
arguments <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
```

Look at `?commandArgs` for more info.

Answer (score 1):

The R import/export manual that comes with the R installation, or is available [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html), has a lot of information on different ways to get your data into R, which is best depends on what your data looks like and how large it is.  It may be as simple as using the `read.table` function, or for large dataset using a database may be better.

If you use `read.table` or similar then your data will be in a data frame and you can run the t test using code similar to this (assuming your data frame is named mydata):

```
t.test(mydata$CANCER1, mydata$NORMAL1)
```

Run `help('[[')` for more details on extracting portions of a data object.